# Nuxt3 navigateTo gives Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, nuxt3

I am trying to programmatically route to a detail page from within a list in Nuuxt3 app:

```html
#/pages/items/index.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
    const gotoDetail = async (itemId) => {
      await navigateTo(`/items/${itemId}`)
    } 
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout name="main-standard">
      
      <template #main-content>
        <div v-for='item in items' :key=item>
          <div @click='gotoDetail(item.id)'
        </div>
      </template> 

      <template #main-content>
        <!-- aside content -->
      </template> 
    
    <NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

And I am getting this error message:

```js
 ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
```

I have searched for an answer and most solutions mention to wrap the `<NuxtLayout>` with a `div`. But that did'nt solve my issue.

I am using a default Layout. So the`<NuxtLayout name="main-standard">` is inside this default layout. Both pages: `index.vue` and `[itemId].vue` are in the `pages/items/` folder.

I am doing something wrong but just can't find it. Does anyone see whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

A few things here are going to break your code.

One, the middle div with the click handler is missing a closing `>`, contents, and a closing `</div>`. (Of course you may have omitted that for brevity)

`items` isn't defined, so there's nothing to iterate over.

You're using the same v-slot name `#main-content` for multiple templates, but each slot name should be unique. The # attributes (shorthand for v-slot) should match the slot names you write in your layout, and those must also be unique within the component.

The main problem looks to be related to the way you're using layouts. To mess with layout on a page using the component, you have to add this into the setup script:

```
definePageMeta({
  layout: false,
});
```

A different way of applying your custom layout to this page is to replace the `false` boolean with the name of the layout, and omit the tag from this page altogether. For that to work, app.vue should have a `<NuxtLayout>` tag wrapping the `<NuxtPage>`

Not a breaking change, but it may also simplify things to write

```
<NuxtLink :to="`/items/${itemId}`">{{ whatever you wanted inside that div }} </NuxtLink>
```

If you need to run code before navigating to that page, you can add it into the top-level middleware folder, and call that named middleware on the page before which you want it to run.